# pass JSON object into php variables

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am sending some data by JSON from a jQuery script to a php file where I am trying to split it up into variables so I can upload it all to a database. So far the JSON data is being sent and recieved as a JSON object but I cannot extract any of the data.

jquery script

```js
<html>
<head>
    <script src="../jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>  
<script>
    function update(){
        var x =  {"1":{"item":"leaks", "qty":"2", "store":"fruitVeg"},"2":{"item":"chicken stock", "qty":"1", "store":"pan"}};
        var dataSend = JSON.stringify(x);
        $.ajax({
            url:"updateTest.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: dataSend,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
                var x = data.item;
                console.log(data);
                //$('#added').text(x +' Added');
            }
        });
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#add').click(update);
    });
</script>   
</head>
<body>
    <div> <input type='button' value='Add to Shopping' id='add'/></div>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP script

```js
<?php
$obj = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$count = count($obj);
$test = $obj[1]['item'];

//echo json_encode ($obj);
echo $count;
echo $test;
?>
```

At present all i get returned is the count number of lines. If I comment out the echo's and uncomment the echo json I get the following returned

```js
{1: {item: "leaks", qty: "2", store: "fruitVeg"}2: {item: "chicken stock", qty: "1", store: "pan"}
```

Comment: https://eval.in/1040616 looks ok to me, although you just get the two values jumbled together into a single string e.g. `2leaks`.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this to work using the following script

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="../jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>  
<script>
    function update(){
        var x =  [{"item":"leaks", "qty":"2", "store":"fruitVeg"},{"item":"chicken stock", "qty":"1", "store":"pantry"}];
        var dataSend = JSON.stringify(x);
        $.ajax({
            url:"updateTest.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: "data="+dataSend,
            success: function(data){
                var x = data.item;
                console.log(data);
                //$('#added').text(x +' Added');
            }
        });
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#add').click(update);
    });
    </script>   
    </head>
    <body>
    <div> <input type='button' value='Add to Shopping' id='add'/></div>
</body>
</html>
```

php looks like this

```
<?php
$list = stripslashes($_REQUEST["data"]);
$obj = json_decode($list);

echo $item1 = $obj[0]->item;
echo $item2 = $obj[1]->item;
?>
```